# EditField And Buttonfield On same Line

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I want to add editfield and labelfield on same line . first editfield and then buttonfield . I have tried many times but it didn't work for me .I have added horizontal field manager and also used tables but none of it can help . The issue is it is not showing the buttonfield,i can see only editfield.  `enter code here`

```
 public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
  /**
    * Creates a new MyScreen object
   */
 public MyScreen()
 {        
     // Set the displayed title of the screen       
     setTitle("MyTitle");



     HorizontalFieldManager m= new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);

     final GridFieldManager   grid  = new GridFieldManager(4,4,0); 

     grid.setColumnPadding(5);
     grid.setRowPadding(5);

     EditField c= new EditField("","",5,EditField.EDITABLE);
  //   m.add(c);
   Border border=BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(10,10,10,10),Border.STYLE_SOLID); 




     grid.setBorder(border);
     ButtonField b= new  ButtonField("Select ",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
     //m.add(b);
     grid.insert(b,1);
     grid.insert(c,0); 
     //add(m);
     add(grid);                          
    } 
 }
```

Comment: post the code that you have tried so far!!

Comment: accept if any of the answers helps.

Answer (score 1):

Override `getPreferredWidth()` of both `EditField` and `ButtonField` like this:

```
public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Display.getWidth()/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override  `sublayout()` and `layout()` method of your `EditField` & `ButtonField` than set its width `Ex: 100` .. now add both this `field` in your `m.add();` .. its works ..